# How to sort jsob array assigned into variable?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a Postgres function that made some calculations on data and assigns jsonb objects into variable of jsonb array type. For example:

> _some_variable := [{"name": "Product 1", "amount": 12, "created":'2021-05-02 12:30:00'}, {"name": "Product 2", "amount": 5,
> "created":'2021-05-01 15:23:00'}, {"name": "Product 3", "amount": 12,
> "created":'2021-05-03 05:12:00'}]

I would like to sort this jsob array by created timestamp key before i return the result from function. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Unpack, sort and repack:

```
SELECT json_agg(v ORDER BY v->>'created')
FROM jsonb_array_elements(
        '[{"name": "Product 1", "amount": 12, "created":"2021-05-02 12:30:00"},
          {"name": "Product 2", "amount": 5,  "created":"2021-05-01 15:23:00"},
          {"name": "Product 3", "amount": 12, "created":"2021-05-03 05:12:00"}]'::jsonb
     ) AS t(v);
```